# Why does my netstream stop reading when ever I `Console.Write` the incoming data?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Here's my fairly simple `TcpClient` method `ClientHandler`.

```
        public static void ClientHandler(object c)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)c;
        NetworkStream netstream = client.GetStream();
        bool connected = true;
        while (connected)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];                   
                netstream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes));  //This line causes the issue

                try
                {

                    Record json_record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes));
                    Console.WriteLine(json_record.Station);
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No longer connected");
                connected = false;
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

Without the commented line, my `ClientHandler` will receive data just fine. If I try to `Console.Write` the incoming data for debugging purposes, I only get the first byte of data and the thread seems to hang.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: That does sound very odd. There are definite issues with the code though - you're ignoring the return value from `netstream.Read` for one thing, and you're also swallowing any exceptions in your inner try block. You're also using `Encoding.Default`, which is rarely a good idea with network traffic - it's better to agree a fixed encoding (typically UTF-8) as part of the protocol and use that. It's possible that none of these is responsible for the problem, but fixing them will help to eliminate other possibilities. What's the other end of the connection doing?

Comment: I unfortunately do not own the other end, so I'm not entirely sure. What I can tell you is I get the same result while using telnet to send simple strings across. If I change my server to act like an echo server, it works just fine up until the point that I add that `Console.Write` line...

Comment: @JonSkeet Could you elaborate on what you said about `netstream.Read`?

Comment: What happens if you change that to `Console.Write(BitConverter.ToString(bytes))`? That way you definitely won't be using any control characters etc.

Comment: The point about `Read` is that it reads *up to* the number of bytes requested. It might read far fewer - whereas you're always using the result as if *every* element of `bytes` had been returned from the server.

Comment: Could be very well an encoding issue. The default is ANSI, but the received stream could have a different encoding. --System.Text.Encoding.Default